# Get response from TCP server in RestController

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

My Spring webflux controller needs to access a remote TCP server. How could I stream the response from the TCP server to the client?

Something like:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://example.com");

....

@GetMapping(value = "/account")
public Mono<String> account() {
  Mono<Account> account = client.get()
        .url("/accounts/{id}", 1L)
        .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchange(request)
        .then(response -> response.bodyToMono(Account.class));

  return account;
}
```

But with a TcpClient (not WebClient).

Thanks,

--nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Spring `WebFlux` is indeed a bit focused on HTTP.

There is a `TcpClient` in reactor-netty, but that's more low level and necessitate a bit of `netty` knowledge (as you will have to perform stuff like framing and decoding yourself). And it doesn't have the notion of a `Response` like the `HttpClient` does, so it's not easily bridged into a `Mono`/`Flux` that you can then transform in your controller...

So I'm afraid at this point there is no off-the-shelf solution to that particular use case :/ I suggest you [open an issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues) though.